# @!/usr/bin/env: No such file or directory when i try to use ros nodes

Tags: python, python-3.x, ros

I tried to write a subscriber and publisher node; but when I try to run the publisher with `rosrun`, it gives me an error: `@!/usr/bin/env: No such file or directory`

Here is the [error](https://postimg.cc/gallery/1xu5yw566/) and the corresponding code (I did `chmod +x`):

Publisher node:

```
@!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String

def publish_it():
    pub = rospy.Publisher("first_msgs",String , queue_size = 10)
    rospy.init_node("publisher_node",anonymous = True)
    x = 1
    z = 10
    rate = rospy.Rate(z) #1/z sec delay

    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        x += 1
        if x == 100:
            x = 0

        msg = "Hi this is our first message . times:" + str(x)
        rospy.loginfo(msg)
        pub.publish(msg)
        rate.sleep()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        publish_it()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

Subscriber node:

```
@!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String

def callback(data):
    rospy.loginfo(data.data)

def iSeeIt():
    rospy.init_node("subscriber_node",anonymous = True)
    rospy.Subscriber("first_msgs",String,callback)
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    iSeeIt()
```

Comment: I assume that your submitted code shows two programs: The subscriber and the publisher, right? Otherwise, the whole construct wouldn't work.

Comment: Ofcourse, they are seperate programs and i dont know why and where but there is a syntax error in publisher node

Comment: What's the reason for using `python3.x` tag? Do you use Python3 in ROS?

Comment: yes, me and my friends learning ROS with phython3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by changing

```
@!/usr/bin/env python
```

with

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
```

I am using python3 and I don't really understand how it works but it works.

Comment: Since the other answers resolved your problem, you should mark one of them as the accepted answer and consider up-voting them if you found them helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You are misusing the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) construct. Instead of using `@!` you have to write `#!`, followed by the interpreter which should be applied to your code. Furthermore, the line (i.e. `#!/usr/bin/env python`) needs to be in the first row of your script. Thus, the head of your subscriber node should look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# subscriber node

import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String
...
```

Comment: i changed it with #! but i got another error in this picture https://postimg.cc/TL48n1sr

Comment: That would actually relate to a new question. Please mark the answer as valid, since it seems that it solved your original question. However, for your new issue you could just install the missing package: http://wiki.ros.org/rospkg#Installing_rospkg

Comment: But i have already installed rospkg.
python-rospkg is already the newest version (1.1.7-100).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 231 not upgraded. (i get this message)

Comment: Again, this should be asked in a new question! But you can ensure that you do not run Anaconda, etc.: https://afsyaw.wordpress.com/2016/12/23/setting-up-ros-on-ubuntu-16-04/

Answer (score 1):

`rospy` init must be placed before the publisher, and your code `shebang` should be as the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String

def publish_it():
    rospy.init_node("publisher_node", anonymous=True)
    pub = rospy.Publisher("first_msgs", String, queue_size=10)
    x = 1
    z = 10
    rate = rospy.Rate(z)
    ....
```

---

[NOTE]:

- Make sure the Python script is executable (`chmod +x mypythonscript.py`)
- If you are using *Python3* in ROS using this shebang (`#!/usr/bin/python3` or `#!/usr/bin/env python3`) instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt-get install python-is-python3
```

write this code it will solve your problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).